# Почему не работает serviceworker-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь разобраться в pwa, но завис на самом начале. Ставлю гем https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails , действую как сказано в инструкции:

1) запустил `rails g serviceworker:install`

2) удалил из application.js строку `//= require_tree .`

3)в layout страницы добавил `%link{rel:"manifest", href:"/manifest.json"}`

Все файлы описанные в разделе "manual setup" присутствуют.
Судя по инструкции, открывая ту страницу, в лэйаут которой добавил линк, в консоли я должен увидеть разные сообщения. Но ничего не происходит.
Версия rails 4.2.0

**Update**
Если зайти на localhost:3000, то сервисные сообщения вижу, если же на test.ru:3000 - нет.
hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   spb.test.ru
127.0.0.1   test.ru
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему дело в https. Настроил  сервер thin на работу с ssl сертификатом и по ссылке https://test.ru:3000 увидел те сообщения, что должен был.

> D-side: "[Также вам необходимо предоставлять ваш код по протоколу HTTPS - Service Worker требует это в целях безопасности.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)"

Comment: Эм-м... ["Также вам необходимо предоставлять ваш код по протоколу HTTPS - Service Worker требует это в целях безопасности."](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) Возможно даже эту ссылку стоит в ответ добавить. А возможно, и процитировать.

Comment: @D-side Почему-то сам до этой статьи не дошел, спасибо за ссылку.